# ASP.NET DateTime with ViewBag doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, datetime, viewbag

I have problems with the `Nullable<datetime>` in the .cshtml file.
I have the following code

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="insc_birth_date" name="Users_naissance" value="@ViewBag.Users_naissance" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}" aria-required="true">
```

And in my controller i have this

```
public ActionResult Submit(Users U)
```

I recovered an item with all property, except the date that returns null all the time ...

how to have a datetime in my item the controller?

Comment: are you missing to fill @ViewBag.Users_naissance from controller ?

Comment: no, because i have in my cshtml  @model NorthwindDailyTrips.POCO.Models.Users